# Jersey + JodaTime = Reading dateTime wrong

Tags: datetime, jersey, jodatime

I'm using Jersey 2.

I send and store the date correctly in the database, and even send the JSON with the correct date millis:

```
//Debbuged using LoggingFilter
{"id":3,"start":1460304000000,"end":1460307600000}
```

As you can see, start is: "Sun Apr 10 2016 13:00:00" and end is: "Sun Apr 10 2016 14:00:00", but when I debug the client:

```
SaveablePersonalSchedule dto = response.readEntity(SaveablePersonalSchedule.class);
```

I get this dates:

```
START: 2016-04-10T16:00:00.000Z
END: 2016-04-10T17:00:00.000Z
```

Got it wrong by 3 hours. This happens with all other Time I've tested: the date is correct, the time is 3hours+.

Any ideas on how to fix this? 
I know I can subtract 3 hours from the given date, but I believe that should be the last resort. Just too ugly hahaha

## More info

Client creation:

```
client = ClientBuilder.newClient(new ClientConfig()
        .register(new JerseyObjectMapperProvider())
        .register(new Jackson1Feature())
        .register(new MultiPartFeature()));
```

Creating the ObjectMapper was the way I found to make jersey SEND the correct DateTime value, because the server was receiving it wrong at first. After this, I send the data correctly and I was able to store it on mysql correctly also.

```
private static ObjectMapper createDefaultMapper() {
    final ObjectMapper result = new ObjectMapper();
    result.configure(Feature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);

    return result;
}
```

## Real Question

How to set TimeZone on Jersey ? I thought it was on the ObjectMapper, but I guessed wrong.

Answer (score 1):

> As you can see, start is: "Sun Apr 10 2016 13:00:00" and end is: "Sun Apr 10 2016 14:00:00"

Maybe in your time zone, but in UTC those millis represent 16:00 and 17:00 - so the result you get is correct.

Convert it to your local timezone if that's what you need.

Comment: That's what I need, but I want jersey to do it for me. Do you know how?

Comment: @MarcoNoronha You can call `jerseyDateTime.toDateTime(DateTimeZone.getDefault())`.

Comment: I cant find it Assylias :( Can you help me? I thought it would be on the ObjectMapper but I guess not.

Answer (score 1):

this should be a matter of timezones. Write eveything in UTC timezone, and read in UTC, then convert to user's target timezone.

Here is a java example ([and gist here](https://gist.github.com/jeorfevre/7b360173a35875fdf4759a862f5c94ba))

```
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

import org.junit.Test;

public class DateTimeTest {

    public static final String PARIS_TZ="GMT+1";


    @Test
    public void datetime(){
        SimpleDateFormat formatterGMT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
        SimpleDateFormat formatterPARIS = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
        formatterPARIS.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(PARIS_TZ));

        Date  date = new Date();    

        log("UTC: "+ formatterGMT.format(date));
        log("PARIS:"+ formatterPARIS.format(date));

    }


    public void log(String s){
        System.out.println(s);
    }

}
```

[Check timezone doc here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html)

Comment: Ok, Is that a way to set the timezone on Jersey it self so it already converts it ?

Comment: A good practice is to store the timezone UTC, so that you know always that timezone is UTC. And after (on the client side) you present it to the client depending on his client timezone (that you get in Javascript for example).  If you need more help can tell me.

Comment: No problem, but I need to know how I can make jersey to make this conversion for me. Do you know how?